# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] The page isn't redirecting properly PHP

Tags: php

I am using `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` on Logout.php page and it is working properly there.But when I have used it on Login page it gives me error "The page isn't redirecting properly PHP" and "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." 
My code is :

```
if($resT==3){
     $_SESSION['userId'] = $_POST["user"];
     header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

`$resT` is the usertype I am getting from database according to the user.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `exit;` after the `header()`

Comment: It's not a very good practice to rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is notoriously unreliable. You can't use it like this unless you're absolutely sure it contains what you need.

Comment: I realy want to redirect user back to the page it came from please help with some other solution .

Comment: Explain clearly wht u need to do? do u want to login the user back if he is not logged in or in which kinda scenarios you want to redirect? There are so many ways of redirecting, dependin on what condition you want to redirect the user will help us to give you the right way for redirecting

Comment: Its an ecommerece site .When the user clicks on add to cart it is redirected to a page that checks if there is a user name stored in session.If there is a user name in session the user gets the shipping form else user is asked to sign in if it is already registered user or go for registration.So , either user goes for sign in or registration it must return back to the page it came from.

Answer (score 2):

This error generally comes when you have loop cycle on the page, means you are redirecting in a cycle that is will not halt. There is some logical error in your page.

`HTTP_REFERER`  Will redirect you to the base address e.g  `http://localhost/`

Therefore check your redirection on the pages where you throw the user.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP_REFERER` is set by client and thus not guaranteed to be available. So, it cannot be used for the any purpose other than logging.

Store initial location in a session or pass it via form parameter.

Comment: I really want to redirect user back to the previous page it came from .

Answer (score 0):

Hi Its better to set your back page to be into session and redirect user to that page.
Like $_SESSION['backfromlogin'] = $currentpage; than use this session variable to redirect back.
your issue is, referrer redirecting to the login page itself. you can echo referrer to make sure.